# Android Bluetooth How to get more information about a service more than uuid

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm using android bluetooth to develop, I know how to get other device's UUID list. My question is: though each UUID represents a unique service, how can I get more information about this service before I build connection to it? Such as what it does and so on.
[This paper](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rudolph/Teaching/Articles/PartOfBTBook.pdf) descripts several attributes of SDP.

Comment: Can you use the `getBluetoothClass()` method on the `BluetoothDevice` instance you have?

Comment: what information you want to get from UUID and its associated service? like battery level of device etc?

Comment: How can I make description of my own service and let other devices know?@ajshort

Comment: Not so complicated, just this service's name and description of it's function.@Jigs

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500452/npe-android-ble-how-to-get-extra-services-like-cycling-navigation-and-speed-u